# Huawei P8 lite is just loading in huawei logo and doesnot start

Tags: updates

I updated the software and when software installed the phone restarted and then phone is just keep loading from huawei logo. I tried to hard reset factory and still same problem. My phone is rooted already. Plz help me if anyone can...thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to flash the stock firmware for your device to get it boots again, Go to this thread [Huawei P8/P8 Lite Firmwares](http://forum.xda-developers.com/p8lite/general/huawei-p8-p8-lite-stock-rom-firmware-t3176374), Download the same build you had before getting stucked or newer one, Extract it and transfer "dload" folder to the root of FAT32 MicroSD, Put the SD in the phone, Hold Vol+ and Vol- with Power button to boot into Upgrading mode, The flashing process will start automatically, Once it done, Your phone will boot to system again.